# jquery How to remove an item with or without a comma/space?

Tags: jquery

Given a Input which can contain values like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="XXXXXXX" />

<input type="hidden" value="XXXXXXX, YYYYYYYY" />

<input type="hidden" value="XXXXXXX, YYYYYYYY, ZZZZZZZZZZ" />
```

I want to use jQuery to remove: XXXXXXX, but if XXXXXXX has a comma after (XXXXXXX,) I need the comma removed to.

**This is what I have now:**

```
uuid = XXXXXXX
.val(attachedUUIDs.replace(uuid + ',', '' ));
.val(attachedUUIDs.replace(uuid, '' ));
```

Ideas to do this cleanly? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
var uuid = 'XXXXXXX';
$('input').val(function (index, value) {
    return value.replace(new RegExp('\s*'+uuid+',?\s*', 'g'), '');
});
```

Comment: this is good but i think something  like this would be better perhaps
`(?i)X{7},?`

Comment: very nice but how do you do that when XXXXXX is a js var?

Comment: Thanks but that's leaving a bunch of white spaces?

Comment: @AnApprentice: It works exactly like my original solution, but inserts the value of `uuid` into the regular expression. Are you sure that there are more whitespaces than before?

Comment: ya positive white space is being left after remove a few of the UUIDs

Comment: @AnApprentice: Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Split in a array the value, using the ',' like separator and then put the second element of the array as your value!! Can this help you?

Comment: +1! This is actually better than by solution. It would be good if you'd provide a code example.

Comment: Var arr = string.split(',');
var last = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < last; i++) {
idx = (item == arr[i]){arr.splice(i, 1);Brek;}

}
return arr.join(separator);

Comment: I am posting from a iPhone, is difficult write better code :)

Comment: @Marco Leo: You can edit your original post and insert the code there.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex in the replace method and mark the comma as optional `?`.

```
$('input:hidden').val(attachedUUIDs.replace(/XXXXXXX,?/, '' ));
```